# angular callback function in controller

Tags: angularjs, callback, repository

how use a callback function in **this.getAllUsers** for get data when get method is finished?

when i run this code **gitData** is empty

```
//REPOSITORY
$provide.factory('UsersRepository',["Repository",function(repository) {
  this.route = '/api/mongoid_users';

  this.getUsers = function(success_callback){
    repository.get(this.route,success_callback);
  };

  return this;
}]);



//CONTROLLER
this.initGitData = function(urlData){
  var gitData = {};
  gitData = {
    allUsers: ctrl.getAllUsers(urlData)
  };
  ctrl.getTypeRepository(gitData);
}

this.getAllUsers = function(urlData){
  usersRepository.getUsers(function(users, status, headers, config){

  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code style is messy (sorry for that!)

If you declare service/repository method, use promise style to wait for result back:

```
//CONTROLLER
this.initGitData = function (urlData) {
    ctrl.getAllUsers(urlData).then(function (result) {
        var gitData = {
            allUsers: result
        };
        ctrl.getTypeRepository(gitData);
    })
};
```

Comment: thx for response but > TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined